# Is there a limit on the number of queries I can make through the Uber API?

Tags: python, uber-api

I am using the Uber API to query certain locations and determine what Uber products are available at each location.

I have been using Python to query 10 - 15 locations all at once, and so far no error has occured.

However, I am wondering if there is a limit to the number of queries I can make per fixed time interval (second, minute, hour, day, week, etc).

So far I am calling `GET /v1/estimates/price` and `GET v1/estimates/time`.

Is there a defined limit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit. The default is 2000 requests per hour. Check https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/rate-limiting

Comment: Thanks. In the URL it says "there is also a short-term rate limit put in place to protect against bursts of traffic" -- Do you know what the short-term rate limit is?

Comment: Check out https://developer.uber.com/support. For example, it says they can be tweeted at UberDevelopers

Comment: Generally speaking (I never used the Uber API but have used several other APIs before), if you wait 1 second between requests, if should be ok. 2 seconds should be very safe